# What are values considered confidential and what are the values considered public when authnticating our Azure Function with Azure Active Directory Ap

Tags: office-365, administration, azure, azure-functions, azure-active-directory

We have created an Azure Function which integrate with Active Directory App.

Here is our active directory App which have a self-signed certificate:-

[image: User's image]

now inside our Azure function we are passing those values to authenticate the Azure function with Azure Active Directory App:-

1. Client Id
2. Tenant ID
3. Certificate Thumbprint

so i think all those 3 values are considered as public , and none of them are actually confidential (similar to secrets or passwords which should not be exposed) am i correct? and if this is the case, then where is the security in passing those 3 values? in other words, how we can be sure that only our Azure function is calling the Azure Ad APP? i am not sure if it is done using the certificate password which we have applied when creating the certificate?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not authenticate using the certificate thumbprint, you instead authenticate using the certificate itself. You can therefore be sure that only you are calling the app because only you have the certificate to authenticate with the app. Worth noting that self-signed certificates should not be used in production and you should instead obtain a certificate from a trusted certificate authority.

[Create a self-signed public certificate to authenticate your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-self-signed-certificate)

Comment: so at the end the private key (the certificate password) is what do the actual authentication?

Comment: The private key is not the same thing as a certificate password, but yes it uses the private key to authenticate with your application.

Comment: ok i see, so my self-signed certificate has a password, public key and private key?

Comment: The password is to protect your private key. I would recommend reading about certificates if you require further information, this is off topic from SharePoint.